# Hook in to add new post link wp admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

How can i customize the **Add new post** link or how can i add my custom parameter in add new post link like **http://www.test.localhost/wp-admin/post-new.php** looks like **http://www.test/wp-admin/post-new.php?lang=fr**

I have customized  the links in menu by

```
global $menu, $submenu;
$submenu['edit.php'][10][2]='post-new.php?lang='.ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
```

But what i want to hook all the links`(post-new.php?lang='')` where ever it appears in the admin panel

Comment: What do you want to do with the hook?

Comment: I have to modify the the add new post link where ever it appears in admin panel

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible. There's no hook for this. These are all the occurrences of `post-new.php` in the core files:

[image]

As you can see, there's no pattern nor common ground nor hook. You need a detailed list of the places you want to change the link, and then proceed with whatever targets them, `global $submenu`, jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the admin_url filter:

```
function add_new_post_url( $url, $path, $blog_id ) {

    if ( $path == "post-new.php" ) {
        $path = "post-new.php?lang=" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
    }

    return $path;
}
add_filter( 'admin_url', 'add_new_post_url', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to consider some ugly looking work?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function (){
    jQuery('a').each( function (){

            //first check that a is pointing towards the link you required
            var pattern = /post\-new\.php/;

            // check that it isn't already containing what you are looking for
            var patternLang = /lang\=fr/;

            // before adding query string make it sure that you would need to append using '?' or '&'
            var patternQString = /\.php\?/;

            var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

            if(pattern.test(href)){
                    if(!patternLang.test(href)){
                        if(patternQString.test(href)) $(this).attr('href', href + '&lang=fr' );
                        else $(this).attr('href', href + '?lang=fr' );
                    }
            }
    });
});
```